# How can I add two sound waves without reaching distortion - always keep them under a certain value?

Tags: waves, acoustics

I'm working on a program that adds sound waves on top of each other. I read that the best way to do that (correct me if I'm wrong) is to simply add them together.

However, this way I easily reach distortion. What's the best way to keep the sound waves always under the volume needed for distortion - and have things sound relatively 'natural'?

I.e., when I'm about to add two samples of two sound waves - what can I do to make sure they don't exceed a certain value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide by the absolute value of the maximum of the new waveform, multiplied by whatever the maximum value the sound system can handle without distortion.  You need to do the absolute value because the waveform varies above and below zero, so the loudest output might be negative.

So if the first waveform is `wv1`, the second is `wv2`, and the the maximum amplitude is `amp`, do:

```
amp*(wv1+wv2)/max(abs(wv1+wv2))
```

Comment: Please note that you can [use $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) on this site to nicely typeset equations.

Answer (score 0):

From a programming point of view, I would add them together as you described, then find the max value of the new wave. After that you compare it to your max volume. Let's say it is twice as loud, so you go back to your new wave and divide everything by 2.